# How to prove $a_{1}\sqrt[b_{1}]{c_{1}}+a_{2}\sqrt[b_{2}]{c_{2}}+.....+a_{n}\sqrt[b_{n}]{c_{n}}$ is irrational?

Tags: number-theory, roots, irrational-numbers

Let's define the number

$$A=a_{1}\sqrt[b_{1}]{c_{1}}+a_{2}\sqrt[b_{2}]{c_{2}}+.....+a_{n}\sqrt[b_{n}]{c_{n}}$$

where $a_{1}, a_{2}, ..., a_{n}$ are positive integers and $b_{1}, b_{2}, ..., b_{n}, c_{1}, c_{2}, ..., c_{n}>1$ are positive integers.

For every $1\leq i\leq n$, $c_{i}$ cannot be divided by any $p^{b_{1}}$ where $p$ is a prime number.

How to prove $A$ is irrational?

Comment: Can you prove it for n=2?

Comment: It's not true as it's currently stated. Take for example $n=1$, then $1\cdot \sqrt[2]{4}$ is not irrational

Comment: @vrugtehagel : $4$ can be divided by $p^{b_1}$, where $p=2,b_1=2$.

Comment: Excuse me, I thought that was a result that the OP got from given conditions. I didn't realize it was a condition.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440453

Comment: One may use the approach given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353337), see also [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWcHy.png) from Kato, Saito _Number theory 2_.

Comment: (Observe that if $A$ were rational then $$a_{1}\sqrt[b_{1}]{c_{1}} \in K := \Bbb Q(\sqrt[b_{2}]{c_{2}}, ..., \sqrt[b_{n}]{c_{n}}),$$ so that the techniques from my above comment apply.)